# Error while implementing Merge Sort [ AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data' ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to merge two sorted Linked lists in python but getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data' error after half execution. Please help me as I am not getting what wrong I'm doing.
As it's executing for the first 3 values but then it's giving error.

```
def mergeList(head1,head2):
    temp1=head1
    temp2=head2
    i=0
    j=0

    while i<3 and j<4:
      if temp1.data<=temp2.data:
        print(temp1.data,end=' ')
        temp1=temp1.next
        i+=1
      else:
        print(temp2.data,end=' ')
        temp2=temp2.data
        j+=1

    while i<3:
      print(temp1.data,end=' ')
      temp1=temp1.next
      i+=1

    while j<4:
      print(temp2.data,end=' ')
      temp2=temp2.data
      j+=1
```

This is the output I'm getting.

```
1 3 5 
3 4 5 6 
1 3 3 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-fcaa90b70961> in <module>()
     59   printList(head1)
     60   printList(head2)
---> 61   mergeList(head1,head2)
     62 
     63 

<ipython-input-27-fcaa90b70961> in mergeList(head1, head2)
     18 
     19     while i<3 and j<4:
---> 20       if temp1.data<=temp2.data:
     21         print(temp1.data,end=' ')
     22         temp1=temp1.next

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you were pretty close to get the right output. I put a comment at the lines that break your code and how you should replace it.

```
while i < 3 and j < 4:
    if temp1.data <= temp2.data:
        print(temp1.data, end=' ')
        temp1 = temp1.next
        i += 1
    else:
        print(temp2.data, end=' ')
        temp2 = temp2.data  # <---- this should be .next
        j += 1

while i < 3:
    print(temp1.data, end=' ')
    temp1 = temp1.next
    i += 1

while j < 4:
    print(temp2.data, end=' ')
    temp2 = temp2.data   # <---- this should be .next
    j += 1
```

You are assigning an integer value to `temp2` while you are still going to treat it as a `Node` in the following iteration. Changing the `.data` to `.next` will make your code produce the following result:

```
1 3 5 
3 4 5 6 
1 3 3 4 5 5 6 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you.Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

THis approach also giving correct answer.

```
def mergeList(head1,head2):
    temp1=head1
    temp2=head2
    
    while temp1 and temp2:
      if temp1.data<=temp2.data:
        print(temp1.data,end=' ')
        temp1=temp1.next
      else:
        print(temp2.data,end=' ')
        temp2=temp2.next

    while temp1:
      print(temp1.data,end=' ')
      temp1=temp1.next

    while temp2:
      print(temp2.data,end=' ')
      temp2=temp2.next
```